# Testing my Django app deployed on azure

Tags: django, visual-studio, azure, azure-web-app-service, python-3.4

I am trying to publish a django app on azure using Visual Studio 2015 Pro. and the azure tools. The publishing completes successfully but when I try to access the application online; I get this: [image]

When I run my local server, the app runs with no problem and I can see the contents without exceptions or errors, but the published version of the app is giving me that error. Please help me solve this problem

Comment: Have you used virtualenv while installing your python packages? According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38931998/django-upgrade-1-9-1-10-error-with-removedindjango110warning-import) either **there are two versions of Django installed** or you need to **upgrade Django** to solve this.

Comment: not all of the modues. mysqlclient could not install because of another error and I tried adding it manuallyand using **wheel**. I also thought I should upgrade django and I did.my version is 1.11.4

Comment: Take a look at (this)[https://github.com/digitalocean/netbox/issues/497]. Are you sure it's using the correct Django path?